# Show x(t) is an element of a subspace E for all t

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, invariant-subspace

Let T be a linear transformation on $\Bbb R^n$ that leaves a subspace $E\subset \Bbb R^n$
invariant and let T(x) = Ax with
respect to the standard basis for $\Bbb R^n$. Show that if x(t) is the solution
of the initial value problem
$$x' = Ax$$

$$x(0) = x_0$$

with $x_0 \in E$ , then $x(t) \in E$ for all $t \in \Bbb R$.

My thoughts: I understand that the subspace being invariant means that for all $x \in E$, $T(x) \in E$. The matrix A in this case is the transformation T on x. I'm struggling to see how to structure this proof though. The solution manual for this particular textbook gives a proof using sequences, but it feels like there should be a simpler route. Does anyone want to take a stab at explaining how to go about this?

Thank you :)

Comment: A user added a helpful comment linking to a different post. Closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to

$x' = Ax, \; x(0) = x_0 \tag 1$

is

$x(t) = e^{At} x_0; \tag 2$

expanding $e^{At}$ in into its power series then yields

$x(t) = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{A^n t^n}{n!} x_0 = \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{t^n A^n x_0}{n!}; \tag 3$

since $E$ is $A$-invariant and

$x_0 \in A, \tag 4$

we have

$Ax_0 \in E; \tag 5$

now if

$A^k x_0 \in E \tag 6$

for some non-negative integer $k$, then the $A$-invariance of $E$ again implies

$A^{k + 1} x_0 = A(A^k x_0) \in E; \tag 7$

the conclusion of this simple induction is that

$A^k x_0 \in E, \; \forall k \in \Bbb Z, \; k \ge 0; \tag 8$

the convergence of the series for $e^{At}$ implies the rightmost series in (3) converges; since every term in this series is a vector in the closed subspace $E$ (closed since finite dimensional), the series converges to an element of $E$; thus

$x(t) \in E, \tag 9$

as was to be proved.